# Clear the cache during runtime - Eclipse e4

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I would like to clear the Eclipse e4 cache (The `.metadata` directory) during runtime.

There are lots of posts for clearing the cache by setting the checkbox in the run configurations but I can't find anything on clearing the cache in the code.

I'd prefer to use a method that has already been written (if there is one) in comparison to writing my own.

If I was to do this myself then I'll do it during `@PostContextCreate` in the life cycle manager.

Is there a method that will do this for me or should I just delete the cache directory?

**Update**
Here is the issue I'm trying to work around.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430090#add_comment

Comment: The .metadata contains all sorts of different things belonging to many different plug-ins. What exactly do you want to clear?

Comment: The layout for all of the perspectives/views. The equivalent of clicking the `Clear` checkbox in the run configuration but instead at runtime.

Comment: @Michael There are two _Clear_ checkboxes in an Eclipse application launch configuration: one in the _Main_ tab to clear the workspace (containing the `.metadata` subfolder) and another in the _Configuration_ tab to clear the configuration area (which is not related to the `.metadata` folder). The `.metadata` contains not only caches, but also preferences, locale file history, not shared launch configurations, etc. which might be in use at run time. A perspective can be reset. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: The saved application model can be cleared with just the `-clearPersistedState` command line option or using `-persistState false` to stop it being saved in the first place. I'm not sure of an API to do that, but `@PostContextCreate` might be too late during the startup anyway to clear this.

Comment: The problem is that we might add a new view to the application. Resetting the perspective wouldn't update this would it?    I can't use -clearPersistedState as it is always called when the application starts. I need it to clear the cache whenever we update the application so I need to check if it has been updated during runtime.

Comment: Currently I have created a `ModelResourceHandler`. When RCP tries to get the cache file I'm checking to see if the application has been updated. If it has been I would like to delete the layout cache. If not then I'd like it to load the old one.

Comment: Instead of deleting the whole `.metadata` I was meaning I'd delete `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workbench.xmi`

Comment: A new view will be show in an existing perspective when using [`org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions`](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_advext_perspectiveExtension.htm?cp=2_0_12_2_1), won't it?

Comment: I've updated my question with a link to the issue I'm trying to work around.

Comment: Deleting the workbench.xmi looks like it would work, I don't think there is any better way currently. E4Application loads the application model immediately after the @PostContextCreate call.

Comment: Yeah looks like the best way to me. If you'd like to answer the question with that I'll accept  :) If not let me know and I'll add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear the cache at runtime I've overridden the `ResourceHandler` and added this to `loadMostRecentModel`.

```
final Method m = getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("getWorkbenchSaveLocation", new Class<?>[] {});
m.setAccessible(true);
final File workbenchSaveLocation = (File) m.invoke(this, (Object[]) null);
workbenchSaveLocation.delete();
```

I use reflection as the parent method is private. It would be better to do this instead of writing code to get the file myself as it ensures I always get the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

First, deleting *.metadata* folder can damage the user data: preferences, launch configs, who knows what else - it depends on particular plug-in implementation.

Also your updates may contain new bundles and fragments with new services and extension. 
And the user may rearrange views and do other things persisted with workbench model.

=>

The deletion of workbench model will not resolve all the issues, please consider the following:

- restart after update to ensure all the new bundles/extensions/services are applied [Howto restart an e4 RCP application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869859/howto-restart-an-e4-rcp-application)
- use Model Processors to manipulate the model after load http://blog.vogella.com/2010/10/26/processors-e4-model/